# MySQL count row values across many columns

Tags: mysql, sum, multiple-columns

I have been searching for a simple way to count my column values across a row using a condition, and this has been taking me to the wild. I need help please as I'm completely new to mysql. my table looks like this:

```
studentid | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun
----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+----
     1    |   1 |   0 |  0  | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0
     2    |   0 |   0 |  1  | 0   | 0   | 0.6
     3    |   1 | 0.3 |  0  | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0
```

and the expected result I am hoping to get is having a count of the columns in the row (ex: studentid = 1), where the column is greater than 0. final result should be something like:

```
studentid | jan | feb | mar | apr | may | jun | Count 
----------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------
     1    |   1 |   0 |  0  | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0   | 3
     2    |   0 |   0 |  1  | 0   | 0   | 0.6 | 2
     3    |   1 | 0.3 |  0  | 0.5 | 0.2 | 0   | 4
```

I strongly need some help please.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no MySQL expert, but I don't think there's an automated way of "unpivoting" the tables in it. You can however, if the number of columns is not variable, just sum them:

```
SELECT *,
  IF(jan>0,1,0) +
  IF(feb>0,1,0) +
  IF(mar>0,1,0) +
  IF(apr>0,1,0) +
  IF(may>0,1,0) +
  IF(jun>0,1,0)
    AS Count
FROM students
```

Not that this is specially performant, but it works: 
[Here's a SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d47d4/1)